# href directive does not work in Angular

Tags: angular, directive

I have set the following directive to catch clicks on all `href`s :

```
    import {Directive, ElementRef, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector : '[href]',
    host : {
        '(click)' : 'doNothing($event)'
    }
})
export class HrefTelDirective {
    @Input() href: string;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        console.log('href loaded');
        console.log(el);
    }

    doNothing(event) {
        // if(this.href.length === 0 || this.href === '#') {
        //     event.preventDefault();
        // }
        console.log('href clicked');
    }
}
```

I load the directive on different modules, including core, shared, etc. but it is never called. When I change the selector to other name like 'myHighlightDirective' it is called.

Comment: No idea. Code looks fine...Might be an import issue. Works fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzjqks?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2flujq